# How to make function like operator<template>() form <functional>

Tags: c++, std

I have method:

```
#include <vector>
#include <numeric>
template <typename T>
class mVector: public std::vector<T> {
    template<typename Operation>
    T accumulate (Operation op, T init = (T)0) {
        typename mVector<T>::const_iterator begin = this->begin();
        typename mVector<T>::const_iterator end = this->end();
        return std::accumulate(begin, end, init, op);
    }
};
```

and I can use it to pass for example `std::plus<int>` like so:

```
#include <functional>
V.accumulate(std::plus<int>());
```

My question is how to make my own function that I will be able to pass this way. For example:

```
V.accumulate(f<int>());
```

Where `f(x, y) = x+y-1`

Comment: What do you want to accumulate with `1/x`? Your function has to take two arguments.

Comment: Sorry. My mistake. I also have something for `std::transform` width 1 parameter.
I tried to make simple function template. I can't find any spec for that and implementation in <functional> is too difficult for me.

Comment: By the way, I recommend you check e.g. [this reference of the standard algorithm functions](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm), check algorithm function you want to use, and what they expect for function. Take [`std::accumulate`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/accumulate) for example, the function reference page says that the function argument should have the signature `Ret fun(const Type1 &a, const Type2 &b)`, together with a list of requirements for the types. Normally all types could (and should) be the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want exactly that syntax, make `f` a functor template:

```
template <typename T>
struct f
{
    T operator() (const T& a, const T& b) const
    {
        return a+b-1;
    }
};
```

Otherwise, you can just use a function template, like in Anton's answer.

Comment: Thanks. I was close, but with `template <class T>`… :)

Answer (score 1):

Given that you have

```
template <typename T>
T f(T x, T y) {
    return x+y-1;
}
```

You can do simply

```
mVector<int> v;
v.accumulate(f<int>);
```